# Performing value_counts() on multiple columns in DataFrame shifts count column to the right after each iteration

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

From a subset of a DataFrame:

```
>>> df[['Source','Destination','Attack Name']].head()

               Source                     Destination    Attack Name
0              10.x.x.116                 10.x.x.71      RDP Enforcement Violation
1              43.x.x.233                 152.x.x.148    Scanner Enforcement Violation
2  hn.kd.dhcp (61.x.x.192)                152.x.x.148    NaN
3             104.x.x.241                 152.x.x.116    Scanner Enforcement Violation
4              117.x.x.61                 152.x.x.52     NaN
```

I want to count the number of attacks from top 10 sources per destination.

I tried something like:

```
import pandas as pd

outReport='test.xlsx'
df = pd.read_csv("IPSLogs2.csv")

def statsPerAttacker():
        topSrc = df['Source'].value_counts()[:10]
        mastaSR = pd.Series()
        for ip in topSrc.to_dict():
                df_statsPerAttacker = df[df['Source']==ip][['Source', 'Destination', 'Attack Name']].value_counts().to_frame()
                mastaSR = pd.concat([mastaSR, df_statsPerAttacker], axis=1)

        with pd.ExcelWriter(outReport, engine='openpyxl') as writer:
                mastaSR.to_excel(writer, startcol=2, startrow=2, header=False)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    statsPerAttacker()
```

I do get the results, but the final column shifts to the right one position after each source IP iteration (see screenshot):

https://postimg.cc/8FBnq07g

What am I doing wrong?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Issue probably raised due to my ignorance of Series and DataFrame objects.
I solved my issue using different approach:

```
def statsPerAttacker():
    topSrc = df['Source'].value_counts()[:10]    
    stats = df.groupby(['Source','Destination'])['Attack Name'].value_counts()
    ips = topSrc.index.tolist()

    statsPerSourceIP = stats.loc[ips]
    with pd.ExcelWriter(outReport, engine='openpyxl', mode='a', if_sheet_exists='overlay') as writer:
        statsPerSourceIP.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='StatisticsByCriticality', startcol=2, startrow=35, header=False)
```